# What is the spatial shape of a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

Let's say a particle is localized in space and its momentum is observed. Does its wavefunction look like a ball spreading in distance with time? How can this be shown mathematically?

Comment: Hint : Solve Schrödinger equation.

Comment: https://www.compadre.org/PQP/quantum-theory/section8_2.cfm

Comment: @KurtG. I hoped on a clear quick response not read this solve that.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341731/how-to-ask-a-good-question-if-you-dont-know-the-subject-very-well).

Comment: When you say that "momentum is known within Heisenberg uncertainty", do you mean that the uncertainty in momentum is as small as can be? In other words, that $\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar/2$?

Answer (score 1):

> Let a particle is localized in space and its momentum is known within Heisenberg uncertainty. Does it wavefunction look like a ball spreading in distance (time).

No. The wave function by [postulat](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html)e leads to the probability of finding the particle at a particular (x,y,z,t). As the simplest solutions of the quantum mechanical equation describing the wavefunction are plane wave solutions, they are not good for modeling a free particle.

> How can this be shown mathematically?

Not in the way you imagine.  One has to go to [the wave packet solution](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) to model free individual particles

[image: wave packet]

There will be  a shape, in the **probability distribution** for finding the particle with a width in the possible energy and momentum.

Comment: This is a 1 dimensional solution. When we go to 3d I think one gets a sphere where the probability is Gaussian on every diagonal. The sphere moves with the speed of the particle and is spreading with distance gone (time elapsed).